# orderer and peer container are exited after a few seconds run ./network.sh up and then i can't create channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I followed the Official Fabric Test Network [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/test_network.html) "Using the Fabric Test Network ", but reported some errors when I run `./network.sh createChannel`. Log and errors like this:

> Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client
> failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection:
> connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp
> 127.0.0.1:7050: connect: connection refused"

Orderer and peer container are exited after a few seconds after i launch the network.sh and then i cant't create channel. I don't understand why.

Comment: What host OS are you using?

Comment: Thank you @GariSingh.  I found my problem. my mistake was that i downloaded multiple fabric image  versions such as 2.3, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, ... . i removed all of them and download only latest version and everything was solved.